# SWIFT iOS8 Alamofire how to build following POST request

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6.1, alamofire

I'm trying to build the following HTTP POST request using Alamofire and Swift. But always i'm posting different POST , and not able to build the request. Could you in build exactly following post request using Alamofire

POST url

Host: myserver.com

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 104

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Origin: URL

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Referer: 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Cookie: __utma=116467794.551251436.1406509450.1412283980.1414556771.5; __utmz=116467794.1414556771.5.4.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _mkto_trk=id:129-KVV-018&token:_mch-exablox.com-1406509450351-30526;

csrftoken=qLTZD4NqzmjGTIE1KmXl7ZFXsB3VRqVp; sessionid=8aec9cacf7a2073c6898cdaaa59194b0

csrfmiddlewaretoken=qLTZD4NqzmjGTIE1KmXl7ZFXsB3VRqVp&username=veeru%40gmail.com&password=password

Answer (score 0):

All typed properties are content-headers of your HTTP(S?) request.

Here is the solution:

```
let headers = [
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "104",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8",
    "Origin": "URL",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Referer": ""
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate"
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
    "Cookie": "__utma=116467794.551251436.1406509450.1412283980.1414556771.5; __utmz=116467794.1414556771.5.4.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _mkto_trk=id:129-KVV-018&token:_mch-exablox.com-1406509450351-30526; csrftoken=qLTZD4NqzmjGTIE1KmXl7ZFXsB3VRqVp;  sessionid=8aec9cacf7a2073c6898cdaaa59194b0csrfmiddlewaretoken=qLTZD4NqzmjGTIE1KmXl7ZFXsB3VRqVp&username=veeru%40gmail.com&password=password"
    ]

let r = Alamofire.request(.POST, "myserver.com", headers: headers)
.response { request, response, data, error in 
    //  do something with local variables
}
```